# How to copy to and run an html5 file present in an Android phone's memory?

Tags: android, html

I am developing an android application, that should open html 5 file when it launches. What I did was

1. I saved the complete  html application under android Assets folder.
2. I am not able to run the html file in the external browser using the path of  assets folder directly, Following code which I used

   ```
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                    Uri.parse("file:///android_assets/mobile/index.html"));
   startActivity(browserIntent);
   ```

An exception is thrown.

1. I send this folder to phone’s internal memory and From there I want to run it.

Qn 1. How can I send a file into phone memory?

Qn 2. And can I run that html file from phone memory?

Is it possible to do so??

Comment: Could you provide the exception here?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to
handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=
file:///android_assets/mobile/index.html }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `file:///android_asset/mobile/index.html` instead. While the directory on the filesystem is `assets/` (plural), the URL format uses `asset` (singular).

Second, you cannot open a Web browser on one of your assets. You will need to either:

1. Copy the files to external storage and launch the default browser on them
2. Copy the files to internal storage, create a `ContentProvider` to serve them, and launch the default browser on the resulting `content://` path

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files) demonstrates the second approach, albeit using a single PDF file than a directory of assets.

A third possibility is for you to display the contents yourself using a `WebView` widget.