# Web view is not showing html data in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-webview, android-view

I am developing an Android app and I have stuck with a strange issue.

I have two buttons : button1 and button2

On clicking on buttons, I am loading different html files from asset folder.

This is working fine on emulators for all versions but on real device which have Android 4.0 or greater, performing a strange behavior.

For button2, It is working fine and showing html pages dynamically in web view but on clicking on button1 it is showing a white page in web view.

I am surprised why so is happening while xml and activities has same code except their ids and name.

I have tried a lot of things and searched but did not get why it is happening with one but not with another?

**Xml for button1 is:**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/xxx">

            <WebView

                android:id="@+id/webViewButton1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layerType="software" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Xml for button2 is:**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/xxxx">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webViewButton2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layerType="software" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Button1 Activity code:**

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public class Button1Activity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button1);
        savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();

        String sign = null;
        sign = savedInstanceState.getString("button1");

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewButton1);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + sign + ".html");
    }
}
```

**Button2 Activity code:**

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public class Button1Activity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button2);
        savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();

        String sign = null;
        sign = savedInstanceState.getString("button2");

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewButton2);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + sign + ".html");
    }
}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261394/1168654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Actually I was putting the above Linear layout under the Scroll View to scroll the Linear layout. As I removed this Scroll view, my web view started working fine and it add vertical scrolling to the contents automatically as it fill the web view height.

So I learnt from this that **WebView does not work properly under scroll view.**